# Seeking European Mountains Shapefile

Tags: topography, data, europe

I am trying to locate a GIS freely downloadable shapefile (preferably polygon) of European main mountain chains (not an elevation data), eg Alps, Carpathian Mountains. I tried variuos sources , including Natural Earth, EEA, and many others, but couldn't find the right data.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Nowadays, I think the place for questions seeking open data is the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 2):

At least for Romanian Carpathians you can find the map of relief units (as polygons) on http://earth.unibuc.ro/download/harta-unitati-relief-romania.

Comment: That's great thanks! I also found shapefile for Alps: http://eusoils.jrc.ec.europa.eu/projects/alpsis/Ecalp_data.html

Comment: @Magda Your link is dead - any chance for update?

Answer (score 2):

There is a dataset available for all European mountain ranges on https://www.eea.europa.eu/data-and-maps/data/european-mountain-areas